# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken on cached page

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having an issue with invalid authenticity tokens for a post request on a cached web page.

I can replicate the error by opening a page with a form on mobile, killing my chrome browser app, reopening and attempting to submit the form. When I do I get the `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` error since the page is not reloaded. I have thousands of pages on my site and I want them to all be cached except for a couple. Also, I have my assets cached from an htaccess file with the following code.

```
<filesMatch ".(css|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|ico|JPG|woff|ttf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=15768000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

How can I tell Rails to cache the HTML on most pages but then on controller specific actions, remove/prevent the HTML caching? Note, I want to continue to cache all of my assets on every page; that I do not want to change.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

After a browser caches your .html page you can't force it to re-fetch this page until the cache period of that asset is expired (i.e. a browser will keep the asset in the cache as long as you specified in `max-age`).

So the right decision here would be to NOT cache any .html file that your server generates dynamically.